# Fix for MonoGame model stretching

Tags: model, monogame

I've recently been working with MonoGame's content pipeline importing custom *.fbx models. I was hoping for some insight as to why the models I'm rendering in the 3D world are being skewed, and if there is a possible fix.

Skewed model [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlPM5.png) in MonoGame.

An update: I've been researching other forums and I finally found some more information. There is a post on the [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105453/monogame-xna-3d-fbx-model-produces-strange-rendering-output) website that has me to believe this is my problem. If I find a way around it, I'll post another update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some tests with [XNA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh7tf.png) and [MonoGame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVPn1.png) side by side. They are the same exact *.xnb file. I attempted to compile it with the MonoGame Pipleline tool. The one I used in both examples is from the XNA compiler. Hope this helps others.